# What code should i add to display the following output using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, console.log

Desired Output:-

> error : You have been disconnected!
>
> warning : You have been idle for 15 minutes

```
// Code starts here

// Do not edit this function

function output(msg) {

   console.log(this.type, ":", msg)

}

 // You may edit below this line not including the .output functions.

var errorMsg = ;

var warningMsg = ;

// Do not edit below this line.

errorMsg.output('You have been disconnected!');

warningMsg.output('You have been idle for 15 minutes');
```

Comment: Please reformat your code and edit your question. Do you want to display errors on a specific site or whats the matter?

Comment: @LajosArpad not homework dude, i was just trying to learn some new stuff and solving some problems from internet..... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function as constructor for your `errorMsg` and `warningMsg` like this :

```
var Logger = function(type) {
  this.type = type
  this.output = output
}

var errorMsg = new Logger('warning');
var warningMsg = new Logger('error');
```

Here is a [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oEZQpj7kvfwPCu2hLz3T?p=preview)
If you have any more question, feel free to ask.

Comment: Actually i need to use the the function that is already defined in the question and get the desired output

Comment: @AvneetSangha This is using your function. `this.ouput = output` is just wrapping your function into the constructor

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you are looking for this:

```js
//Desired Output:-

console.error("You have been disconnected!")

console.warn("You have been idle for 15 minutes");

console.log("Code starts here")

// Do not edit this function

function output(msg) {

console.log(this.type, ":", msg)
}
```